# (Basic) statistics

Tags: python, statistics, descriptive-statistics

I got a misunderstanding regarding basic statistics (I think) but I can't get my head around that:
I did an online survey regarding the usage of some application. The user could answer 1 (I don't know that application), 2 (I know that) or 3 (I use that).
Now I want to know, how many applications the average user uses:

```
df['iuse'].mean()
```

where df['iuse'] was calculated as the count of answer 3 in one returned answer.
The result is something like 2.2.

Now, I want to know, how many applications a user of application X uses:

```
f = df['q1_1'] == 3 # For application 1, filter all answers where the user uses that
df.loc[f,'iuse'].mean()
```

That returns a number above 2.2 - for every single app: In short (and ugly):

```
[(4.235294117647059, 85),
 (4.966666666666667, 60),
 (2.7495274102079397, 1058),
 (4.609195402298851, 87),
 (6.391304347826087, 23),
 (4.122950819672131, 122),
 (4.850746268656716, 67),
 (3.1860068259385668, 586),
 (2.72192513368984, 1122),
 (3.520231213872832, 346),
 (4.276595744680851, 94)]
```

(left is the mean, and right is the count of answers for that application)

Now: Why is the usage overall less than the usage when seen from a specific application? I would expect to have at least some numbers below the total mean, but they are all above that. I'm confused :(

Thanks for any pointers and help
Klaus

Comment: **First:** The answer in iuse is encoded (by you) as a number, but it is a so called categorical value. That means that you cannot apply just any operator on it: Not equal works, but a mean definitely does not.  *For the connoisseur: It seems ordinal, so you could rank it.* **Second:** Could you include a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: OP: it **would** be clearer if you provided a sample frame.
@SvanBalen, it sounds like the 'iuse' column has been generated.  Each row is a user/response, with columns for each answer, like 'q1_1', and _those_ are encoded 1/2/3; but 'iuse' then is just a row-wise count of qi_j==3.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll make sure to include a better example next time, but for now @BenReiniger has given a good explanation

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes it could be a derived feature. Nevertheless it remains a categorial value, and taking the mean is... *wait for it* ... *mean*ingless

Comment: @SvanBalen  'iuse' is a count variable; discrete, but numerical, not categorical.   The mean of that is perfectly sensible. I'd agree about the mean of any of the qi_j's...

Comment: Ahhh, I think you are right! In that case my previous statements are retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily unexpected (or broken).  Imagine that users tend to use none or all of the applications.  For a specific example, suppose 90 users use no apps at all, and 10 use all (say) 11 of them.

Then the average apps used by a user is $(90\cdot0+10\cdot11)/100=1.1$, but for each app, the average app-usage of a user who uses that app is $(10\cdot11)/10=11$.  (In your case, for a sanity check maybe compute the number of users who use no apps.)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to explain it (at last for now :))